# How to define alignment in stylesheets in PySide6?

Tags: python, qtstylesheets, pyside6

In `PySide2` we could use `"qproperty-alignment: AlignRight;"`, but this no longer works in `PySide6`. Since there are changes in `PySide6` and shortcuts are no longer supported I've tried:

- `Alignment.AlignRight`
- `Qt.Alignment.AlignRight`
- `AlignmentFlag.AlignRight`
- `Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight`

but nothing seems to work.

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QLabel('Window from label')
window.setStyleSheet('qproperty-alignment: AlignRight;')
window.setFixedWidth(1000)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Qt6 no longer interprets the text "AlignRight" but requires the integer values, for example Qt::AlignRight is 0x0002 so a possible solution is to convert the flags to integers:

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QLabel("Window from label")

window.setStyleSheet(f"qproperty-alignment: {int(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)};")
window.setFixedWidth(1000)

window.ensurePolished()

assert window.alignment() & QtCore.Qt.AlignRight

window.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Was the original method working in PySide2 though? Works for me with the int, but not with AlignRight.