# In PyQt6/PySide6, how can we use qproperty-alignment in Qt Designer and in external qss files?

Tags: python, css, alignment, pyside6, pyqt6

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244996/in-pyqt6-or-pyside6-is-it-possible-to-do-alignment-with-css-stylesheet) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411504/how-to-define-alignment-in-stylesheets-in-pyside6) questions, it appears that in PySide6 (6.3.1), we have to convert PySide6 flags to intergers to do alignments in a style sheet.

For example, we can define a style sheet in the main .py like so :

```
style_sheet = f"""
    QLabel{{
        border: 1px solid black;
        qproperty-alignment: {int(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)};
    }}
"""

...

window.setStyleSheet(style_sheet)
```

The neat trick is to use f string.

This works but what if we want to use qproperty-alignment :

- in a style sheet defined in Qt Designer ?
- in an external style sheet defined in .qss ?

If I am not wrong, we can't use f string in either cases.
As a result, to see alignments in Qt Designer, we have to use Qt Designer properties.

I think that would be one more big loss compare to Qt5 if there is no workaround.

Comment: What puzzles me is: why do you need to set the alignment property with QSS?

Comment: To "see what I get" in Qt Designer. As I wrote,  I don't mind using the Style Sheet editor of Qt Designer applied to the MainWindow, not necessary QSS (just CSS in an external file that can be loaded as a resource in Qt Designer) but I'd like to see what my app will look like when I do Crtl-R in Qt Designer. Obviously, any styling in the main .py file won't appear in Qt Designer.

Comment: In PySide2 or PyQt5, qproperty-alignment worked in the style sheet editor of Qt Designer. Didn't it?

Comment: Any solution providing a 100% CSS styling method visible in Qt Designer is fine to me. An external QSS/CSS file was just an idea. I would like to avoid mixing CSS styling and properties styling methods.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I want to understand why you need to set the alignment using stylesheets instead of using the *actual* property.

Comment: I think I answed already. To do all the styling  in Qt CSS. To avoid mixing 2 methods. I love clean code. But what I need does not matter. The fact is that If there is no workaround, this is an issue, not a blocking one, but still a  issue I hope they will fix soon. Specially because it used on work in Qt5 and it's broken in Qt6.

Comment: The thing is, while `qproperty` does allow to set properties, it's generally discouraged (mostly because it only works when the widget is polished). Also, while it *does* have visual results, conceptually speaking the text alignment isn't really about *styling*, at least not in the sense of Qt styling: QSS and CSS share many concepts and mechanics, but while CSS also covers layout aspects, QSS does not: in fact, there's no alignment QSS property, except for those related to sub control positioning. I completely agree with you that it's an issue that should be fixed, considering that the ->

Comment: -> documentation doesn't make any reference about it and one, rightfully, expects that it should work, but the fact remains: conceptually speaking, the text alignment of a label is *not* directly related to "styling" in the Qt sense. I can understand that there's a thin "gray area" in there, but Qt properties are, for their nature, unrelated to styling. The fact that we could set them with QSS is an "extra feature", but we shouldn't rely on that too much for this kind of matter. Also, conceptually speaking, it would make more sense to use specialized subclasses with a specified alignment.

Comment: Thanks for your detailled explanation  @ musicamante. I will try to make sense of it all in the coming days or weeks when I dig deeper into Python Qt. I need more time and knowlegde to understand why qalignment is related more to layout than styling.